# Identifying separable differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time verifying if

$ \frac{dy}{dt} + p(t)y(t) = q(t)y(t) + 3$

is a separable differential equation.

I've tried refactoring $p(t)y(t) - q(t)y(t)$ as $r(t)y(t)$ and I came to

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 3 - r(t)y(t),$ with $r(t) = q(t) - p(t)$

I'd think that this isn't a separable equation just because of the three standing there. I've read a couple books about, but I can't wrap my mind about a definitive answer.
Can somebody help?

Comment: I think you're right, I don't believe that's separable because of the $3$. You can solve it with the integration factor method though, if $r(t)$ has an antiderivative

Comment: If i had an 3 y(t), instead of just a 3, that would make it separable, right?

Comment: Yes, because then you would do $r_2(t) = 3 - r(t)$ and you would have $\frac{dy}{dt} = r_2(t)y$.

Comment: Please check your source. Could it be that your equation was intended to be a Bernoulli equation $y'+py=qy^3$? Then the naming convention and separation of terms is a standard form.

Comment: It wasn't, @LutzLehmann, but thanks for the help!